# Retaining data selection selected in components?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have two html pages named index.html and index1.html.index.html has some multiselect drop down and index1.html has multiselect check box. i am linking both the pages as below.

```
index.html
-------------

<a class="button right" href="index1.html">Continue</a>

index1.html
-------------

<a class="button right" href="index.html">Previous</a>
```

These are just mockup screens. The problem is after selecting the data in index.html and if user tries to navigate to index1.html and if he comes back to index.html then the data selected in index.html is lost.

My question is how can i preserve the selection even if user switches between different pages?

Thanks!

Comment: Persist the selection via a cookie or session variable?

Comment: Could u plz give me some code snippet....

Comment: How secure does the selection need to be? What have you tried? Have you attempted to Google for a possible answer?

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5, maybe this could help you:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp